# Host angular-MVC .net Core Application in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, webpack, gulp, web-hosting

How to Host a **Angular2-MVC** application developed using Visual Studio in IIS.

1. Using Gulp or Webpack ??
2. Is it possible to get Typescript or Javascript files without bundling in the browser which would be useful for debugging.

Thanks for your help in advance.....

Comment: Did you try publishing it?

Comment: Yes we published it .. but my concern is is it possible to retain the javascript files as it is wiithout minimizing.....

Comment: Does this help with debugging minified script: http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/debugging-debugging-minified-javascript.html